# How can I get the last/end offset of a kafka topic partition?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm writing a `kafka` consumer using Java. I want to keep the real time of the message, so if there are too many messages waiting for consuming, such as 1000 or more, I should abandon the unconsumed messages and start consuming from the last offset.

For this problem, I try to compare the last committed offset and the end offset of a topic(only 1 partition), if the difference between these two offsets is larger than a certain amount, I will set the last committed offset of the topic as next offset so that I can abandon those redundant messages.

Now my problem is how to get the end offset of a topic, some people say I can use old consumer, but it's too complicated, do new consumer has this function?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The new consumer is also complicated.

`//assign the topic
consumer.assign();`

`//seek to end of the topic
consumer.seekToEnd();`

`//the position is the latest offset
consumer.position();`

Comment: This does not work if you just want to calculate the difference between your client current offset and latest known kafka topic offset!

Comment: @hiaclibe possibly use of `getWatermarkOffsets` will return the earliest and latest offset for the given topic and partition: https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.0/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.Consumer.html#Confluent_Kafka_Consumer_GetWatermarkOffsets_Confluent_Kafka_TopicPartition_

Comment: Is `assign()` necessary here?

Answer (score 41):

You can also use the kafka server command line tools:

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic topic-name
```

Output is of the form `<topicName>:<partitionID>:<offset>`, e.g. `t1:0:0`, see
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-tools-GetOffsetShell.html for further details.

Answer (score 16):

For Kafka version : 0.10.1.1

```
// Get the diff of current position and latest offset
Set<TopicPartition> partitions = new HashSet<TopicPartition>();
TopicPartition actualTopicPartition = new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition());
partitions.add(actualTopicPartition);
Long actualEndOffset = this.consumer.endOffsets(partitions).get(actualTopicPartition);
long actualPosition = consumer.position(actualTopicPartition);          
System.out.println(String.format("diff: %s   (actualEndOffset:%s; actualPosition=%s)", actualEndOffset -actualPosition ,actualEndOffset, actualPosition));
```

Comment: how does it compare with the method provided by [lynn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38448775/1630604)?

Comment: Tested it a bit and for a topic with 2.5k elements over 1k calls there is an improvement of ~1.5 ms between this solution and the one of [lynn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38448775/1630604) (respectively 5.1722ms compare to 6.7226ms)

Comment: technically that code would show the difference between the position of the next topic to be read and the end offset. If you have autocommit set to false, then this won't show you the actual position of the last commit as the last commit may be further back than the next one to be read.

Answer (score 6):

I have developed below code to fetch Offset Status

```
import java.util
import java.util.{Collections, Properties}

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.{PartitionInfo, TopicPartition}
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class GetOffsetRange(consumer:KafkaConsumer[String,String]) {

  def getStartOffsetRange(topic:String):util.HashMap[TopicPartition,Long]={

    val topicPartitionList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic)
    val partitionMap=new util.HashMap[TopicPartition,Long]()
    val arrTopic=new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]()

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

    for(topic<-topicPartitionList.asScala){
      println(topic.topic() +","+topic.partition())
      arrTopic.add(new TopicPartition(topic.topic(),topic.partition()))
    }

    consumer.poll(0)

    consumer.seekToBeginning(arrTopic)

    for(partition <- arrTopic.asScala){
      partitionMap.put(partition,consumer.position(partition)-1)
    }
    return partitionMap
  }

  def getEndOffsetRange(topic:String):util.HashMap[TopicPartition,Long]={

    val topicPartitionList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic)
    val partitionMap=new util.HashMap[TopicPartition,Long]()
    val arrTopic=new util.ArrayList[TopicPartition]()

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));

    for(topic<-topicPartitionList.asScala){
      println(topic.topic() +","+topic.partition())
      arrTopic.add(new TopicPartition(topic.topic(),topic.partition()))
    }

    consumer.poll(0)

    consumer.seekToEnd(arrTopic)

    for(partition <- arrTopic.asScala){
      partitionMap.put(partition,consumer.position(partition)-1)
    }
    return partitionMap
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = ...
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
consumer.poll(0);
consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
long currentOffset = consumer.position(topicPartition) -1;
```

Above snippet returns the current committed message offset for the given topic and partition number.

Comment: is the `poll(0)` needed?

Comment: Since consumer.poll(0) is deprecated. You can use consumer.poll(java.time.Duration.ZERO);

Comment: @DanielAlder the approach is a bit hacky as there is no native support. I will recommend test it at your end to validate if it's required or not. Also, the behavior might change with different Kafka version.

Answer (score 4):

since kafka 1.0.1, consumer has a method called endOffsets

public java.util.Map endOffsets(java.util.Collection partitions)

Please let me know if you need full code..

Please refer
[apache-kafka-1.0.1-javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)