# Is it possible to know the consumed offset of given Kafka consumer group through java program?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Is it possible to know the consumed offset of given consumer group through java program. Of course we can get know using  below consumer group command

> bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --describe --group  kafka-grp --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the LATEST offset of a kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428196/how-can-i-get-the-latest-offset-of-a-kafka-topic)

Comment: `kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand` is a Java class that you can import and use in your own code, yes.

Comment: More specifically, you can copy the majority of the code from that class https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/ConsumerGroupCommand.scala