# How to get last offset for all topic partition?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I need to get last offset for all topic partitions each N seconds (for cache purpose). What `API` should I use for that? I think, I need the most reliable and fast way.

I know two approaches:

1) [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38448775/1756750):

```
//assign the topic
consumer.assign();

//seek to end of the topic
consumer.seekToEnd();

//the position is the latest offset
consumer.position();
```

2) Second one:

```
consumer.endOffsets()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `consumer.endOffsets()` is the better approach.

The first approach requires actually assigning the topic, which sounds like you don't need.