# How to get the latest value from a kafka Stream

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am fairly new to Kafka and streaming.I have a requirement like every time I run the kafka producer and consumer I should get the only message produced by producer.

Below is the basic code for Producer and consumer

Producer

```
 val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test", "key", jsonstring)
    producer.send(record)
    producer.close()
```

Consumer

```
val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
    props.put("group.id", "13")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, Map[String,Any]] = new KafkaConsumer[String, Map[String,Any]](props)
    consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList("test"))
    while (true) {
      val record = consumer.poll(1000).asScala
      for (data <- record.iterator){
        println(data.value())

      }
```

The Input Json I am using is the below

{

"id":1,

"Name":"foo"

}

Now the Problem I am facing is each time I run the program I am getting the duplicated values.For example If I run the code twice the consumer output looks like this

{

"id":1,

"Name":"foo"

}

{

"id":1,

"Name":"foo"

}

I want the output like if I run the program the only message that is processed by producer should be consume and should be printed.

I hv tried few things like changing the consumer properties for offset to latest

```
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
```

I also tried things mentioned like below but it didnot work for me
[How can I get the LATEST offset of a kafka topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428196/how-can-i-get-the-latest-offset-of-a-kafka-topic)

Can you please suggest any alternatives??

Comment: Are you using same group.id on for each call? seems like you are changing it

Comment: @sun007 yes I am changing it.Actually I am not getting any message in consumer if i dont change the group id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consumer** read messages from a topic partition on sequential order.
If you call to poll(), it returns records written to Kafka that consumers in our group have not read yet. Kafka tracks their consumption offset on each partition to know where to start to consume in case of restart.
Consumers maintain their partition offset in topic __consumer_offsets by using commit.

> Commit is the action of updating the current position in
> __consumer_offsets.

If a consumer restarted, In order to know where to start to consume, the consumer will read the latest committed offset of each partition and continue from there.

You can control the commit by two ways either set auto-commit true with commit interval

***1.By enable.auto.commit true***

```
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
```

**2.Manual commit**

```
consumer.commitAsync();//asyn commit
or  
consumer.commitSync();//sync commit
```

If you fail to commit it will restart from the last committed position as shown on below pics

[image]

**auto.offset.reset:**

Once the consumer restarted the first time it uses **auto.offset.reset** to determine the initial position for each assigned partition. Please note when the group first created with a unique group id, before any messages have been consumed, the position is set according to a configurable offset reset policy ***(auto.offset.reset)***. After that, it will continue consuming message incrementally and use commit (as explained above) to track the latest consume message

> Note: If the consumer crashes before any offset has been committed,
> then the consumer which takes over its partitions will use the reset
> policy.

So in your case

1. Either use manual offset commit or enable.auto.commit true for auto-commit.
2. Always use the same group id if you change group if it will treat different consumers and use auto.offset.reset to assign offset.

Reference: https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/

Comment: this solution worked.Can you please suggest any book or article to get the understanding of kafka

Comment: Please refer https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/