# How to get Kafka Producer messages count

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I use following code to create one producer which produces around 2000 messages.

```
public class ProducerDemoWithCallback {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerDemoWithCallback.class);

String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

    // create the producer
    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);


    for (int i=0; i<2000; i++ ) {
        // create a producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record =
                new ProducerRecord<String, String>("TwitterProducer", "Hello World " + Integer.toString(i));

        // send data - asynchronous
        producer.send(record, new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                // executes every time a record is successfully sent or an exception is thrown
                if (e == null) {
                    // the record was successfully sent
                    logger .info("Received new metadata. \n" +
                            "Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
                            "Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
                            "Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
                            "Timestamp: " + recordMetadata.timestamp());


                } else {
                    logger .error("Error while producing", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // flush data
    producer.flush();
    // flush and close producer
    producer.close();
  }
}
```

I want to count those messages and get int value. 
I use this command and it works, but i am trying to get this count using code.

```
"bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TwitterProducer --time -1"
```

and the result is

```
- TwitterProducer:0:2000
```

My code to do the same programmatically looks something like this, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to get the count:

```
 int valueCount = (int) recordMetadata.offset();
 System.out.println("Offset value " + valueCount);
```

Can someone help me to get count of Kafka messages offset value using code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at implementation details of [GetOffsetShell](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/GetOffsetShell.scala).

Here is a simplified code re-written in Java:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GetOffsetCommand {

    private static final Set<String> TopicNames = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        TopicNames.add("my-topic");
        TopicNames.add("not-my-topic");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopicNames.forEach(topicName -> {
            final Map<TopicPartition, Long> offsets = getOffsets(topicName);

            new ArrayList<>(offsets.entrySet()).forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println(topicName + ":" + offsets.values().stream().reduce(0L, Long::sum));
        });
    }

    private static Map<TopicPartition, Long> getOffsets(String topicName) {
        final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = makeKafkaConsumer();
        final List<TopicPartition> partitions = listTopicPartitions(consumer, topicName);
        return consumer.endOffsets(partitions);
    }

    private static KafkaConsumer<String, String> makeKafkaConsumer() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "get-offset-command");

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    }

    private static List<TopicPartition> listTopicPartitions(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer, String topicName) {
        return consumer.listTopics().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(t -> topicName.equals(t.getKey()))
                .flatMap(t -> t.getValue().stream())
                .map(p -> new TopicPartition(p.topic(), p.partition()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

which produces the offset for each topic's partition and sum (total number of messages), like:

```
my-topic-0=184
my-topic-2=187
my-topic-4=189
my-topic-1=196
my-topic-3=243
my-topic:999
```

Comment: it works really well. its implementation is done using consumerConfig. isn't it possible with ProdcerConfig?

Comment: No, because it is using the Consumer API. There is no way to retrieve offsets metadata from the Producer API (as producers in Kafka basically do not care about offsets).

Comment: one last clarification. if there are multiple topics, e.g let's say i have 3 topics and i want to count for each topic.

Comment: You can run the code multiple times for different topic names or refactor `.filter(t -> TopicName.equals(t.getKey()))` to compare with multiple topic names, e.g. `.filter(t -> TopicNamesSet.contains(t.getKey()))` where `TopicNamesSet` is a `Set` with all desired topic names.

Comment: Thanks. it works efficiently. I want to add one last functionality in the above code to complete it. should i ask this as a separate question? The code return results like this                 
my-topic-0 =2000
not-my-topic-0 =2000

I tried to compare the values of these two elements of set but didn't get it correctly. All i see over SO and internet is the comparison of two sets. 
But i am trying to compare the values of these two elements in set. something like this 
    if (my-topic.count == not-my-topic.count)
    {
      System.out.println("They are equal");
   }

Comment: I took your previous code as it was easy to follow. I make Set as you mention above and change TopicName.equals(t.getKey())) to filter(t -> TopicNamesSet.contains(t.getKey())) . I thought it would be easy to loop over those two elements in the set and compare their count results but it seems a bit difficult to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get that value? If you share more detail about the purpose, I can give you more good tip.

For your last question, it's not the correct way to get the count of messages with the offset value. If your topic has one partition and the producer is one, you can use it. You need to consider that the topic has several partitions.

If you want to get the number of messages from each producer, you can count it in the callback function that is onCompletion()

Or you can get the last offset using Consumer client like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "your-brokers");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

Consumer<Long, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic_name");

Collection<TopicPartition> partitions = consumer.assignment();

consumer.seekToEnd(partitions);

for(TopicPartition tp: partitions) {
    long offsetPosition = consumer.position(tp);
}
```

Comment: Producer will produce the messages and those messages will be store in an application mean database. Then i need to compare the results. From database side, i can take count. but on the producer side i don't know how to deal with it. Is there any possibility that i get this count as integer so that i can compare with database count value?. Can you give some idea or examples?

Comment: Ok, I think you can get the last produced offset position using my second answer. And then you can compare it with your database. maybe this one also helpful info for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428196/how-can-i-get-the-latest-offset-of-a-kafka-topic