# Reliably get the last (already produced) message from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am doing something like the following pseudo code

```java
var consumer = new KafkaConsumer();
consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
var beginOff = consumer.beginningOffsets(topicPartitions);
var endOff = consumer.endOffsets(topicPartitions);
var lastOffsets = Math.max(beginOff, endOff - 1));
lastOffsets.forEach(consumer::seek);
lastMessages = consumer.poll(1 sec);
// do something with the received messages
consumer.close();
```

In the simple test that I did, this works, but I wonder if there are cases, like producer crashes etc., where offsets are not monotonically increasing by one? In that case, **would I have to `seek()` my way back in time, or can I get the message offset of the last already produced message from Kafka?**

I am not using transactions, so we don't need to worry about read-committed vs. uncommitted messages.

**Edit:** An example where offsets are not consecutive is after log compaction. However, log compaction should always keep the last message, as it is - obviously - more recent than all preceding messages (same key or not). But the offset before that last message could theoretically have been compacted away.

[image: Kafka Log Compaction]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the last/end offset of a kafka topic partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428196/how-can-i-get-the-last-end-offset-of-a-kafka-topic-partition)

Answer (score 1):

In [kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html), it is clearly mentioned that, [consumer.endOffsets](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-)

`Get the last offset for the given partitions. The last offset of a partition is the offset of the upcoming message, i.e. the offset of the last available message + 1.`

So when you get that `endOff - 1`, it is the last available Kafka record for that topic partition when you fetched that. So producer concerns are not impacted for this.

And one more thing, Offset is not decided by the producer. It is decided by the partition leader of that topic partition. So, it is always monotonically increasing by one.

Comment: A lot has happened since Kafka 1.0, but the docs for 2.8 state something similar: `In the default read_uncommitted isolation level, the end offset is the high watermark (that is, the offset of the last successfully replicated message plus one)`. That sounds pretty definitive, and I hope it is true. But I remember having to cope with non-consecutive offsets, but now I'm not 100% if that wasn't perhaps due to read_committed... Will try to check that.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky Shall i update the answer according to your comment?

Comment: Your answer is convincing, but seems to be wrong - or there is a bug somewhere. I have documented such a case here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69186310